# Background fixed and overflow-y:scroll

Tags: html, css, background, screen-resolution

I have an image as background on my site, I set it to be fixed and overflow-y to scroll (so that image should remain "static" and not scroll. The problem is that it has a certain height! Everything works well with some displays/resolutions but not for others!

As a temporary fix I set the background to repeat-y fixed center top but it looks ugly when repeated... is there a way to have the background fixed for all resolutions (so no blank spaces if on higher resolution)?

Thanks in advance, here's the link to better understand what I'm talking about :)

```
carminella DOT it/beta/chi-siamo/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this with Full Page Background jQuery Scripts such as Backstretch:

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Or you may achieve this through CSS3:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/quick-tip-full-page-background-images-in-css

Hope that helps!

Thank you!

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as the limit ends (5 minutes). :)

Comment: Sure, now it says "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes". :)